# Leibniz rule for poly-harmonic operators

Tags: differential-operators, harmonic-functions

It is well-known that, for two smooth functions $u,v$ defined in $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($n\geq 2$), the laplace operator shows $$\Delta (u v) = v\,\Delta u + 2\,\nabla u\,\nabla v+u\,\Delta  v,$$what if the above  $\Delta$  raplaced with poly-harmonic $\Delta^m $ with integer $m\geq 1$? Does there exist similar result for the expansion $\Delta^m(uv)$? Thanks for any references and welcome for any comments.